# FTP permission Paradox

Tags: ftp, user-controls

I've a VPS with debian, apache 2.0, php, everything! (nope, just the essential).
I need to give acccess to some user to specific folder. (different, but base is `/var/www/` and every user should have a personal folder)

I managed to create accounts that have a specific home, and can't "browse" up (**hard... but i did searching in WHOLE google**).

Well, they **can't create**, modify enything in that folder (their home).
If I try with one of these account, it gives me:

```
Response:   550 Rename failed.
```

Well, I think: permission error, than i do

```
chown user path
/etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

I enter with user in ftp, and try to login, **error**:

```
Response:   500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
eError: Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

Well, I've to `chown root path` to let user access againt to fpt.

Again, no right to edit/create/delete, I think: **OK!** chmod 777 the entire folder and sub..

```
Response:   500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
eError: Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

So, this is an impasse, and obviously I'm doing something wrong.

I've now googled the error, and found: edit `vsftpd.conf` adding:

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
allow_writable_chroot=YES
```

(Just in case I had vsftpd-ext instead of vsftpd)

Here how I created the account for ftp

1) `/# useradd -d path -s /dev/null user > /dev/null 2>&1`

2) Edited **etc/shells** file adding this: `/dev/null`

3) Edited **etc/vsftpd.conf** removig comment on

```
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
```

Thanks to anyone can help, and sorry if my english is really bad, but I think you should blame Italian School System... okok, **my** fault!

Comment: With the command 'allow_writeable_chroot=YES' it give same error in login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

After a lot of trouble (really, A LOT!), i found what was the problem, and fixed:

Problem is Debian 7 + vsftpd 2.x

This vsftpd versione doesn't allow `allow_writeable_chroot=YES`

Fortunately some angel found this bug and created a fixed version of vsftpd.

To use it just:

1. Add

   > deb http://ftp.cyconet.org/debian wheezy-updates main non-free contrib

   to sources.list with this command

   ```
   echo "deb http://ftp.cyconet.org/debian wheezy-updates main non-free contrib" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list.
   ```
2. `aptitude update`
3. `aptitude install -t wheezy-updates debian-cyconet-archive-keyring vsftpd`
4. `echo "allow_writeable_chroot=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd.conf`
5. `/etc/init.d/vsftpd restart`

After doing this you can create an account and use writable root inside chroot(), with the method I posted in question.

Thanks to [The Frontier Group](http://blog.thefrontiergroup.com.au/)